# Converting IList<string> to List<string>()

Tags: c#, list, ilist

I have a function that takes `IList<string> someVariable` as a parameter. I want to convert this to a list so I can sort the values alphabetically.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you actually need to sort the list, or just iterate over it in a particular order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can just do

```
var list = new List<string>(myIList);
list.Sort();
```

or

```
var list = myIList as List<string>;
if (list != null) list.Sort; // ...
```

Comment: Just because the given `IList<T>` isn't specifically a `List<T>`, doesn't mean you can't sort it.  [`ReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) implements `IList<T>` but isn't a `List<T>`.  You should still be able to make a copy of it and sort it.  The second example you posted is wrong.

Comment: maybe I was not 100% clear in this - it's not wrong it's just not working in this kind of situations (Sort will just not be called) - but thank your for the hint - I guess there are enough examples here to pick one :)

Comment: How is *not working in this kind of situation* not wrong?  The reason `IList<T>` presumably **how** the given `IList<T>` is implemented is an unimportant implementation detail that could change without warning.  Your second example would silently start to fail.  I'd say forcing an explicit dependency where there isn't one is **wrong**.

Comment: Your first example is exactly what I was after. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
IList<string> someVariable = GetIList();
List<string> list = someVariable.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

IList implements IEnumerable.  Use the .ToList() method.

```
var newList = myIList.ToList();
newList.Sort();
```

Comment: I think you need to call `.Cast<>` before `.ToList`

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq to sort an `IList<string>` like so:

```
IList<string> foo = .... ; // something
var result = foo.OrderBy(x => x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to convert to a List to sort things. Does your sorting method require a List but not accept an IList. I would think this is the actual problem.

Furthermore if you really need a List, if your IList realy is a List (which is somewhat likely) you can just interpret it as such. So I would first check if it is already a List before creating a new one

```
var concreteList = parameter as List<T> ?? parameter.ToList();
```